# Why is an "id" not from Mongodb automatically created, and how to disable it

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65ea05dbaa907e05219c0934"
  },
  "id": 6,
  "title": "asd",
  "content": "asd",
  "author": "asd",
  "category": "asd",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-03-07T20:21:52.000Z"
  }
}
```

I couldn’t find the answer to the question on the Internet and gpt

Comment: Did you check out the [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#field-names)? It is used as primary key and cannot be disabled. You can simply assign your value in `id` to it if you don't want to have 2 id fields.

Comment: @ray no. You can disable it. See answer below.

Answer (score 4):

For posterity. *The `_id` field is created by the MongoDB server and used by the server so you cannot delete that by default. It is 12 bit binary data.*

Nevertheless, this is not what the OP asked.

> Why is an "id" not from Mongodb automatically created, and how to disable it

Djongo mimics Django’s ORM and so just like in Django, an `AutoField` (AUTOINCREMENT field) is implicitly added to your models. This is the `id` field you automatically get.

But if you explicitly add an `ObjectIdField` (internally sets `primary_key` as `True`), the implicitly created `AutoField` (AUTOINCREMENT field) will not be added.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField() # <—- no more id field after this.
    # •••Rest of your Model•••
```

*Fun fact: using the `ObjectIdField` in your models will save you from calling Django migrations every time you create a new model.*